# NSButton argument binding doesn't pass argument?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have a `NSCollectionView` with a `NSButton` in the collection view item. The xib's owner is set to my `BatchListViewController` and the controller has the method

```
@interface BatchListViewController : NSViewController
-(IBAction)another_click;
@end
```

I set the binding for target to be:

[image: target binding]

This works fine but I also want to send the underlying model to the `another_click` method. According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSButton.html),

> The objects specified in the argument bindings are passed as parameters to the selector specified in the target binding when the NSButton is clicked.

So I set the binding for argument to be:

[image: argument binding]

This runs fine if I keep the selector method's signature the same `another_click:` but if I change it to

```
-(IBAction)another_click:(id)arg;
```

I get the dreaded error:

> BatchListViewController another_click]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

What am I doing wrong? Apple's docs say this is possible but I haven't been able to find an example of this working. Even other SO threads are saying [this isn't possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104191/nsbutton-setaction-selector) but that can't be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon is part of the method signature, and you've forgotten to include it when setting up your bindings.

Comment: I love you. I've been troubleshooting this for a few days.

Comment: I had tried `another_click:(id)arg` in the selector but I didnt think of just doing the colon.